# Update factory in spec

Tags: rspec

Here's my folder factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :folder, class: Folder do
    name { Faker::Lorem.word }
    parent_id nil
    user_id nil
  end
end
```

and here's my context block:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }      
let(:asset) { FactoryGirl.create(:asset) }

context 'when in folder' do
  before do
    delete :destroy, id: folder.id
  end

  it{}
end
```

Now, the resulting expectations all fail because while the folder factory is created, it's user_id, is nil.

How should I update it with the user's id? I don't want to do it in the factory file if possible, I like keeping my factories netural...I just need to update its user_id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, user_id: 123) }
```

Comment: Urgh. I knew this but I've been working so hard my brain's turned to jelly. Thanks though :)